# Creating Jackpot steam CSGO bot

Tags: javascript, php, bots, steam

I just registered on this site and I need little help. So I made a website about csgo betting and I made everything work except one thing: My bot. So he should accept trades max 10 items and minimum 50 cents in total. But when I send trade,it says "Can't get prices,declined trade". So there is my code of getting prices from steam:

```js
<?php
$item = $_GET['item'];
$item = str_replace("\"", "", $item);
$item = str_replace("\'", "", $item);
$item = str_replace(" ", "%20", $item);
$item = str_replace("\\", "", $item);
@include_once ("pdocon.php");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name=?");
$stmt->execute(array($item));
$rs = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(!empty($rs)) {
        if(time()-$rs["lastupdate"] < 604800) die($rs["cost"]);
}
$link = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$item;
$string = file_get_contents($link);
$json = $string;
 
$obj = json_decode($json);
//print $obj->{"median_price"}; // 12345
//$obj = json_decode($string);
if($obj->{'success'} == "0") die("notfound");
$lowest_price = $obj->{'median_price'};
$lowest_price=str_replace("$", "", $lowest_price);
$lowest_price = (float)($lowest_price);

//$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM items WHERE name=?");
//$stmt->execute(array($item));
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE items SET `cost` = ?,`lastupdate` = ? WHERE `name` = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($lowest_price, time(), $item));
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO items (`name`,`cost`,`lastupdate`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($item, $lowest_price, time()));
echo $lowest_price;
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am new to this site so don't mind if I put this code thingy wrong,I am not sure how to do it..And tell me if I need to include some other codes like code of bot or something..

Comment: 1. Please understand that this website is not intended for solving specific problems, but general. Don't expect anyone to rewrite your code for you. 2. Please provide an Item hash for testing.

Comment: Huh, the box where i should type title it says specify your problem and I saw some posts about problems with steam bot too..What do you mean item hash for testing?

Comment: Sorry then.. I didnt know.

Comment: +The fact that you will probably scam peoples.